# How to Display the attribute value and not the ParentEvent Object in the Foreign key dropdown?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-filters

I have the followiung models:

```
class ParentEvents(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=70)

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    side_list = models.TextField()
    parent_event=models.ForeignKey('ParentEvents')
```

now when i registered the Event class in admin.py it displays "ParentEventObjects" in the dropdown list of foreign key.
How can i change it so that instead of ParentEventObjects it displays the name field of the parent event.
thanks in advance  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `__unicode__` attribute for the name to show up.

```
class ParentEvents(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=70)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.name
```

The same for `Event` model as you would run into similar issues for the same.

Read more on [`__unicode__` here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode)

Comment: There's probably some complicated way to display something different in the admin by writing a custom widget.  But this answer is certainly the most straightforward and also most useful elsewhere! (And also a good practice to follow in general anyway!)